# how to solve winerror 5? , Access is denied in Command prompt , powershell and VS code

Tags: python, pip

I have already tried to install the latest version of PIP and still I'm not able to use it in python program , as well as the administrator permission was also granted
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FvJj.png)

Comment: A Stack Overflow question needs to have enough information to be answerable -- typically, a [mre] -- included **as part of the text of the question itself**. Images (and links) do not count; see [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/14122)

Comment: That said -- a good place to start is to create a virtualenv in a directory you own. It's normal and expected (and good practice!) for an unprivileged user not to have permission to install packages in a systemwide Python installation's site-packages directory. Also, note the answer in the linked duplicate mentioning `--user`.